# Frequencies for a normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics, probability, normal-distribution

How to get frequencies that reflect a normal distribution for each integer `1...400`.

Values 1 and 400 would have the minimum frequency of 1, what would the frequencies be for the other values?

Also, what if we would want the frequencies be in the case of the integers `1...300`. Is there a general expression to get frequencies for normality?

EDIT:

Here's a start of what I am looking for:

```
probability_weights <- choose(400, 0:400)

sample(1:400, 400, replace=T, prob=probability_weights)
```

The issue is that this will get a sample, whereas I'd like to get definite population frequencies (so basically just scaled down the huge triangle probabilities).

Comment: The normal distribution density function has two parameters (mean and variance) and does not describe a discrete distribution. You seem to want something (what?) different.

Comment: @Roland Possibly attaching values from a Pascal's triangle? The issue is that these values get so extreme for 400 values. I do not want to lose the relative probabilities though.

Comment: Imagine we want a normal distribution for `1...5`, we could use the 5th row of the triangle (1, 4, 6, 4, 1). If we use these frequencies, it would be (as I assume) close to a normal distribution. Problem is that the 400th row has a highest value of  1.009189e+119. I do not see how I can turn this into a distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the binomial distribution:

```
binom <- function(k,p,n) choose(n,k)*p^k*(1-p)^(n-k)

p <- binom(0:399,0.5,399)

plot(p/min(p))
```

[image: binomial distribution]

```
p[1]/min(p)
#[1] 1
p[400]/min(p)
#[1] 1
```